# What is the name for group of people who line up to create a corridor?

Tags: phrase-requests, expression-choice, idiom-requests

What is the proper name for group of people who line up in two lines to form some kind of a corridor for other people to pass between the two?

http://mc-k26.ru/images/com_fwgallery/files/62/livcor_02.jpg

Comment: Actually, I think the group of people "parts" creating a passage instead. The idea may have evolved from there, to purposely lineup (schoolkids, et al.) on either side of a passage to receive dignitaries.

Comment: Good question!  You could be thinking of the term "running the gauntlet" (just google).  I've also heard a term something like "honour line" or "parade of honour" or "honour corridor" or something, but I can't quite think of it.  Consider googling around about weddings and the like.  Star Wars films tend to end with one of these, right? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a term ***[guard of honour](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/guard-of-honour)*** that is mainly used in military and sports.

> a group of people, usually soldiers, who are arranged in a row at a special occasion such as a marriage ceremony or an official visit, to honour someone very important

---

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_of_honour):

> In association football, in recent years teams have shown their appreciation to the champions of their own division. This involves the players of one team applauding the league winners (the other team) as they appear onto the pitch.
>
> **The applauding team forms two lines to make a corridor**, and the league winners run through the corridor, single file.

[image]
<sub>Jamie Carragher receiving a guard of honour from teammates and opposition players on the final match of his career.</sub>

Comment: The phrase Guard of Honour, or Honour Guard, is also used at a wedding as the couple leave the church.

Answer (score 2):

If used is a negative sense, this is a **gauntlet**.  You would send a prisoner down the line and the men would beat or switch him to the end.

Comment: I've heard it used in a neutral sense as well, for exactly this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would reserve "receiving line" or "welcoming line" for a one-sided line.

If it's just a corridor, that's a gauntlet. I don't think there's any negative connotation in contemporary use.  Aisle would definitely work with neutral connotation.

Comment: Please include links to your sources. Posts without attributions are likely to be considered low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard people refer to it as an [**aisle of honor**](http://wesconnect.wesleyan.edu/s/1318/index_social.aspx?sid=1318&gid=1&pgid=1570&cid=3005&ecid=3005&crid=0&calpgid=788&calcid=2838), or just simply an *aisle*.

Depending on the specific context, it can also be called *welcoming line* or *send-off line*.

Answer (score 0):

In U.S. sports, the corridor that [teammates](http://www.zimbio.com/pictures/p4wVDrkJLwB/Oakland+Athletics+v+Los+Angeles+Angels+Anaheim/pU9cA8DP_MY) or [fans](http://westseattleblog.com/2013/05/hope-lutheran-students-step-outside-for-2nd-annual-walk-a-thon/) form is often called a *tunnel*. In some settings, the temporary structure is termed a "[victory tunnel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmMoB92z78s)." Though some tunnels include a ceiling created by having each participant hold hands with the person opposite (as in the video above), many do not; such ceilings tend to appear only when very small people are passing through the open space of the corridor. It might make more sense to call the lineup of fans in some tunnels—like [this one](http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/news-photo/jon-hayes-of-the-boston-cannons-runs-through-a-tunnel-of-news-photo/173086622)—a *ditch* or a *trench*, but *tunnel* remains the preferred term.

Outside the realm of sports, the same concept of creating a corridor walled with people is sometimes termed a "[human tunnel](https://www.facebook.com/aprl.org/posts/619677391384696)."